# Entity edit doesn't save in ASP.NET MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, http-post

I got a form for editing my user info:

```
<form asp-action="EditUser"  asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="User.Id" />

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="User.Name" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="User.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="User.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="User.Surname" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="User.Surname" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="User.Surname" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my MVC action:

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("EditUser")]
    [Authorize(Roles = Roles.Root + "," + Roles.Manager)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var studentToUpdate = await _dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);

                // Try to update user from DB by edited values from form
                if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<ApplicationUser>(studentToUpdate, "User.",
                    s => s.Surname, u => u.Name))
                    _dbContext.SaveChanges();

                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
      }
}
```

In debug I could see that in `Request.Form` property there are new right values, but DB entity hasnt updated. How could I fix that?

Comment: Does your breakpoint hits the line => `_dbContext.SaveChanges();`?

Comment: I don't know how different asp.core is from mvc, but shouldn't your action expect for a `User` variable in its parameters?

Comment: For an edit, only need one await reekeeS.

Answer (score 0):

We normally use a view model as a parameter, and bind the posted value to it. Then update the record base on it.

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("EditUser")]
[Authorize(Roles = Roles.Root + "," + Roles.Manager)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, EditViewModel model, 
    string returnUrl = null)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        var studentToUpdate = await _dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);
        if (studentToUpdate != null)
        {
            studentToUpdate.Surname = model.Surname;
            ... Other properties

            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```